# C# Threading with Selenium

Tags: c#, multithreading, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm developing a C# application that opens browser and executes different tests on the same webpage. It works perfectly single-threaded, but right now I'm trying to implement multi-threading into the application, and I'm running into some issues. First, it start normally, I have a thread delay, so each thread will only open after 20 seconds, so there are no resource leaks, everything works fine until a point where I get the "Unable to connect to the remote server". The server did not ran out of resources, since I'm keeping a close eye at it, I just think there are some issues with my code.

This how I start the threads:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => Bot.StartBot(conf))
        {
            IsBackground = true
        };
        thread.Start();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(conf.thread_delay * 1000);
    }
```

and this is how I start the browser:

```
public static IWebDriver CreateBrowser(String string_proxy)
{

    try
    {

        var cService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        cService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("--proxy-server=" + string_proxy);
        options.AddArgument("--silent");
        options.AddArgument("--log-level=3");
        options.AddArgument("--lang=en");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-logging");
        options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-infobars");
        options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.images", 2);


        return new ChromeDriver(cService, options);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        try { File.AppendAllText("errors.txt", e.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine); } catch { }
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return CreateBrowser(string_proxy);
    }
}
```

I cannot find any information or guides on how to run multiple threads efficiently with selenium on C#.

Thank you.

Comment: if you can, try to avoid quitting any driver/browser until all threads have been launched.  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @pcalkins thanks for the help, but sadly, each browser will login with a different account, do its job and exit after, so the threads need to kill driver/browser and start a new one for each account. I know this is possible, since I've seen simillar software that does the same, but my program has this strange error, not sure why...

Comment: it may be grabbing the wrong sessionID.  (the sessionID of a closing instance)  You may want to log those.  (I think driver has a "getSessionId()" method.) I'm curious about this quirk myself and haven't seen a definitive solution yet.

Comment: @pcalkins I found the solution. I didn't saw that I was using driver.Close() instead of driver.Dispose(). After changing that, it's working now! Thank you anyway!

Comment: ahh.. orphaned browser or driver?  driver.quit() should work too.

Comment: @pcalkins none, the issue with quit is that it leaves some resources open, and if you push the server too much, it will crash due to memory leaks, not enough cpu power, etc, with driver.quit() you are wasting resources

Comment: @pedroribeiro98 Could you post your working code please? I’m facing a similar problem while running Selenium 4 under xUnit.

Comment: @MattW I no longer have this code, but from what I can remember, the solution was the one presented above, using dispose or quit instead of the close method.